# Can't receive emails with vestaCP

Tags: linux, email, centos

I installed VestaCP on a clean Centos 7. Everything works great except the email; I can send emails, but I cannot receive any. I've tried this hint from here: https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=10730#p40115 but it did not work.

Also I've tried to see what the problem is through http://www.checktls.com and everything seems to be fine.

Any ideas on what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve this problem with this page too:

https://www.mail-tester.com/

Anyways.. I see you solved it using later version of clamav
//https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=10730#p40115

Comment: actually this solved my issue:
`mkdir /var/run/clamav/` and 
`сhown clam:mail /var/run/clamav/`

https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=10832&p=40574#p40570

Comment: Perhaps make an answer for the rest of us and mark it answered?